# Navigation through 360 photos on mobile

Tags: android, ios, panoramas, virtual-reality

This may sound silly, but I need a solution for this problem. I want to create an indoor virtual offline navigation using 360 photos, and being able to click on arrows to navigate through the pictures.
My problem is, I want to find a way to link various 360 photos to create the sense of navigating (e.g. going from a room to another), but only using the phone camera to create the 360 photos.
I saw this on Google street view application. I am able to create 360 photos but i cannot navigate inside them as shown in Google examples.
Any ideas please?

Comment: 360 photos to get a 360-degree room or for multiple rooms?

Comment: you need to find out some good library

Comment: something like this : https://www.google.com/streetview/#rio-hotels-and-restaurants/hotel-fasano

Comment: I can't understand how you can navigate through when you click? is it a collection of 360 photos linked together?

Comment: @Hana what library did you use to create 360 degree image?

Answer (score 0):

Look at out this [library](https://github.com/ashqal/MD360Player4Android) its render video and image both to 360 you can also move to navigate picture and video while using touch functionality.

Comment: Im sorry i don't understand. Are you saying that I can create 360 photos and link them together using this library?

Comment: no just pass the uri of your picture to this library there is a sample in this library use that sample you will know every thing what i said :)